# how to alternate words in typewriter effect with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

right now I am practicing javascript and I wanted to make a typewriter effect to a text, showing character by character, then pause for 1 second and then remove one by one. I already did this part and it works for me, but I want to do a couple more things, the first is that I want to print a different word every time the previous one is deleted, these words will be predefined inside an array to iterate with them, the second is Let this be done indefinitely.

Next I show you what I have, which is to print and delete a word:

Html:

```
        <div class="slog-container__text">
            <p>NOS ENCANTA CREAR</p>
            <p></p> <!-- here printwords --> 
        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
    const contenedorParrafo = document.querySelector(`.slog-container__text`);
    const parrafo = contenedorParrafo.lastElementChild;

    const arrPalabras = [`SOLUCIONES`, `ARTE`, `IDEAS`]; //words with which I want to iterate
    let palabra = arrPalabras[0];

    const maquina = palabra =>{
        let arrCaracteres = palabra.split(``); 
        let i = 0;
        const mostrarCaracteres = setInterval(()=>{
            if(i === arrCaracteres.length){
                clearInterval(mostrarCaracteres);
                setInterval(()=>{
                    let caracter;
                    const quitarCaracteres = setInterval(()=>{
                        arrCaracteres.pop();
                        caracter = arrCaracteres.join(``);
                        parrafo.innerHTML = caracter; 
                        if(arrCaracteres.length === 0){
                            clearInterval(quitarCaracteres);
                        } 
                    },150); //wait time to delete character
                },1000); //timeout to switch from printing to deleting characters
            }else{
                parrafo.innerHTML += arrCaracteres[i]; 
                i++;
            }
        },150); //wait time to print character
        }

        maquina(palabra); // here i execute
```

this works for me to show and delete a word, but I have tried to iterate with the others and I have not succeeded, I also want to make this function be done indefinitely

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the error is with other examples? And what other examples did you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const contenedorParrafo = document.querySelector(`.slog-container__text`);
const parrafo = contenedorParrafo.lastElementChild;

const arrPalabras = [`SOLUCIONES`, `ARTE`, `IDEAS`]; //words with which I want to iterate

var isWindowFocused = true;

const maquina = (palabra, index) =>
  new Promise((res, rej) => {
    let arrCaracteres = palabra.split(``);
    let i = 0;
    const mostrarCaracteres = setInterval(() => {
      if (i === arrCaracteres.length) {
        clearInterval(mostrarCaracteres);
        const removeChars = setInterval(() => {
          let caracter;
          const quitarCaracteres = setInterval(() => {
            arrCaracteres.pop();
            caracter = arrCaracteres.join(``);
            parrafo.innerHTML = caracter;
            if (arrCaracteres.length === 0) {
              clearInterval(quitarCaracteres);
              clearInterval(removeChars);
              // if its the last word call the print function again and start over
              if (index === arrPalabras.length - 1) print();
              // resolve the promise after all chars have been deleted
              res("done");
            }
          }, 150); //wait time to delete character
        }, 1000); //timeout to switch from printing to deleting characters

      } else {
       //if there's more characters printed than the actual word ,start over
        if (parrafo.innerHTML.length >= arrCaracteres.length && parrafo.innerHTML !== arrCaracteres) {
          parrafo.innerHTML = '';
          console.log("start over")
          clearAll();
          return print();
        }
        parrafo.innerHTML += arrCaracteres[i];
        i++;
      }

    }, 150); //wait time to print character   
  })

const print = () =>
  arrPalabras.reduce(async(prevPromise, palabra, index) => {
    //wait for previous task to be done
    await prevPromise;
    // start the next task
    return maquina(palabra, index)
  }, Promise.resolve());

print(); // here i execute

// clear all intervals
const clearAll = () => {
  const interval_id = window.setInterval(function() {}, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
  for (let i = 1; i < interval_id; i++) {
    window.clearInterval(i);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slog-container__text">
  <p>NOS ENCANTA CREAR</p>
  <p></p>
  <!-- here printwords -->
</div>
```

Comment: It works but it has a slight problem, it happens that when I change the tab in the browser or I have the view in a program window, the functionality is broken and it prints more characters, apart from them they are printed in an order that takes away the coherence of the word, for example: _**AARRRTTTEEEE**_, _**DDIIIEEEAAASSSSS**_

Comment: @rj.dev Edited the answer, added a condition before adding the other letter, if the printed word's length is more thant or equal to the length of the actual word, but its value is not the same as the word, clear all of the intervals and start over . See if the problem is solved.

Comment: if it works the way you reframed it, thank you very much, I haven't learned how to handle promises in javascript yet, I find myself still learning at the junior level, thanks again!!